# Does Blender2.8 havea Zbrush-style cursor for sculpting?

Tags: 3d-cursor, zbrush

I mean that cursor of ZBRUSH thats projecting on the mesh .

Comment: Can you show a screenshot or post a link to what feature you mean?

Comment: When You sculpt in blender on ZBRUSH Kthe cursor follows the mesh normals .you can understand what I mean in that link bro https://code.blender.org/2019/06/sculpt-mode-features-branch-status-report/